# Parsing RepeatedFields in proto3

Tags: c#, protocol-buffers, protobuf-csharp-port, proto3

A simple 'Person' object is parsed as

```
            Person person = new Person
            {
                Id = 1,
                Name = "Foo",
                Email = "foo@bar",
                Phones = { new Person.Types.PhoneNumber { Number = "555-1212" } }
            };
            using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                // Save the person to a stream
                person.WriteTo(stream);
                bytes = stream.ToArray();
            }
            Person copy = Person.Parser.ParseFrom(bytes);
```

How is a RepeatedField<> parsed?

EDIT: The question is if RepeatedFields can be sent through the wire or do they have to be bundled in a message to be passed around?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. `Person` is a message, but `repeated Person` is a field _in_ a message, not a message. Are you asking if you can write / read a single entry of a repeated field at a time? If so I am pretty sure the answer is no, you must read/write an entire message at a time. If you're asking about the internals of parsing... no idea, but you could always dig into the source code if you were really interested!

Comment: The former - I was beginning to wrongly think that a repeated Person could be sent as a message. If you add that as an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: added, plus some more info I discovered since I was curious how this worked under the hood :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Person` is a message, so you can read and write a single instance of it, as in your example. `repeated Person` is a field *in* a message, not a message itself. You cannot read/write a repeated field, you have to read/write an entire message at a time. (Looking at [the Python implementation](https://github.com/google/protobuf/blob/master/python/google/protobuf/internal/encoder.py#L199), it appears that the encoder needs to know how long the message is in order to encode it properly, so this makes sense.)

However, there are a couple alternatives to the scenario you described:

1. You could send a bunch of single `Person` messages, and gather them together at the receiving end in whatever way you need.
2. You could define a message, let's call it `People`, containing a single field `repeated Person` and write that message. In the [documentation for encoding](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/encoding?hl=en#optional), they note that both concatenating the strings of two messages or calling the `Message::MergeFrom` method will concatenate repeated fields in messages. So, you could send any number of `People` messages and concatenate or merge them on the receiving end. This would get you a single `People` message containing every `Person` that was sent, without having to know up front how many `Person` messages will be sent.